# multiple tables select

Tags: php, sql

I don't know if it's possible but this is what I want to do. 
I have three tables

Accounts

```
id | username | pass
```

Cars

```
id | plate | id_ac | kilometers // in the id_ac I add manual the id of the car's owner.
```

Trips

```
id | plate | places | date | active
```

Now I want when the user is logged in to see tha Trips that are active with his car.
So I want to

```
SELECT from Trips the plate, places, date WHERE active=0 AND id= ? (the logged user's id)
```

But the table trips doesn't have the id of the owner of the car. So I want somehow to select the values of the table Trips of the car that logged user owns.

Any idea how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at table joins. This looks like it is what you are looking for:

`SELECT t.plate, t.places, t.date FROM Trips as t JOIN Cars as c ON t.plate = c.plate WHERE t.active = 0 AND c.id_ac = ?`

Have a look at this. This is a pretty nice way of explaining the table joins. 
http://www.sql-join.com/sql-join-types

I am not getting into DB architecture and deeper stuff, but it can help you with your task at hand

Comment: That is the correct way on how to join tables later on, however he has to fix his database structure first and implement user_id as foreign key in trips table.

Comment: @davidev I totally agree he has stuff to improve and study there. That's why I added a link from where he can start studying and getting into deeper stuff. But this works for this specific case.

Comment: If in his use case the cars make the trips then his schema is OK because he has the plate as foreign key already. It doesn't look like accounts that make the trip he's got 1 account many cars and 1 car many trips.

Comment: It's a headache to me. Didn't work. I don't want to add owner's id in the Trips template because is one day a car change owner I want the new onwer to be the one who can see the trips that his car did in the past. That's why I'm looking for a solution with the SELECT. I've tried JOIN before and I think you are right and thank you for the link, I will study more.

Comment: @NebulaBoy It will still work... you will store the user id and the car id to a trip. If you want to view all your tracks of one car (regardless of the driver) you will just join with the car id. If you want to see only the tracks one person drove, you will join with the user id inside of trips.

Answer (score 0):

What you are referring to is primary and forgein key.

Your primary key is a unique key, which can identify every record in your table. In your user table that is the id. It has to be unique.

When you are now creating trips in your trips table, you will have to "link" your record to the specific user. Here you are referring to the primary key in user's table. So you have a new column `user_id` inside your `trips table`, where you will store the user id, who is connected to that trip.

When using the user id in other tables, you are having a "foreign key".

For each trip you will have to create a foreign key for the `car` and for the `user`. This can be the `number plate` and the `user id`.

If you want to see all the tracks for a specific user, you can make a `JOIN` with the user id in tracks. If you want to see all tracks for one car, you will just `JOIN` with the plate.

(I can just suggest reading some information about primary/ foreign key. It is fundamental when designing a database structure as you did above.)

Comment: I don't want to have user's id into the Trips table because if the car change owner one day I want the saved trips of the car to be visible only to the new owner. And I don't want to have to change the owner's id from all the trips after that.

Comment: Okay, no I understand it. Thanks for the clarification. So basically, you will need to map each trip to a user. Has I understand a user drives the trip and each trip is connected to a car aswell. A user can drive many trips, however every trip has exactly one car mapped.

Comment: So will have to store the car_id in the trip and the user id. Even though the user won't own the car later one, you can still view all his trips as they are mapped to a user. The car plate won't change, however the owner of the car can.

Comment: But if the car change owner, I want the new owner to be able to see all the trips that car did before, but the old owner couldn't see them anymore. Like a trip diary of the car. So when a car change owner the acount_id in the Trips table must also change. That's why I wanted to find a way to avoid the account_id into the Trips table. But I'm still confused ... :( :(